# Linux: Daemon and Daemon output to be logged in a file

Tags: linux, nohup

I am using the below command to run my python code as a daemon on the server.

```
nohup python mycode.py >> log.txt 2>&1 &
```

For some reason unknown to me only few lines are getting written to the file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `nohup python mycode.py &>> log.txt 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 1):

nohup itself writing output in `nohup.out` so no need to redirect output to log.txt,bydefault all output will be redirected to nohup.out

Comment: I am redirecting the nohup.out output to my log.txt file

Comment: @AnkitSolanki: But why? you can use nohup.out file itself